# Providing delegate methods as a package author

Tags: javascript

I am working on a npm package that is supposed to be consumed by others. I decided that the package should provide functions that make working with objects defined in my package easier. Specifically functions that "delegate" to methods.

For example `bark`

```js
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Dog.prototype.bark = function bark() {
  return `${this.name}: Woof!`
}

function bark(dog) {
  return dog.bark()
}

// Example use of bark.
console.log(
  [ new Dog('Spike') ].map(bark)
)
```

However I realized it is also possible to implement it the other way around; making `Dog.prototype.bark` delegate to `bark`:

```js
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Dog.prototype.bark = function bark() {
  return bark(this) 
}

function bark(dog) {
  return `${dog.name}: Woof!`
}

// Example use of bark.
console.log(
  [ new Dog('Spike') ].map(bark)
)
```

My question is: should a package author prefer one style over the other or is there no difference?

> I hope there is a good reason to prefer one over the other, otherwise we have another style to endlessly debate over.

Comment: It really depends on the use case. If `bark` does any kind of complex logic, or relies on the inner state of dog in any way, it seems as though it would be better to have that logic encapsulated into the class (option 1).

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Making the decision based on if the method needs to access (conceptually) "private" properties is an option. However, when you look at the result, it still seems rather arbitrary.

Comment: But it's not, because I also said "relies on the inner state", meaning that if you have "subclasses" and the like it becomes more difficult to implement. Arguably I'd say the pattern itself isn't particularly useful in this scenario to begin with, but again, it depends on your real world scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider you are implementing two classes, `Dog` and `Wolf`, which both implement the interface `Canidae` meaning they have a `bark` method.

Most of the time, you will want the `bark` method to delegate to `Dog.prototype.bark` or `Wolf.prototype.bark` method, depending on the object you are passing.

```
// Dog class
function Dog(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Dog.prototype.bark = function bark() {
  return `${this.name}: Woof!`
}

// Wolf class
function Wolf(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Wolf.prototype.bark = function bark() {
  return `${this.name}: Woooooooooooooooh!`
}

// Delegating method
function bark(canidae) {
  return canidae.bark()
}

// Example use of bark.
console.log(
  [ new Dog('Spike'), new Wolf('Jack') ].map(bark)
)
```